# format text_field helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, strftime, textfield

Is it possible to apply strftime formatting to the value of a text input field using a Rails text_field helper?
In the form I use for creating or editing a record, I have a text input field which is populated by a variant of the calendardateselect javascript. I click the text field and a little calendar pops up. After I select year, month, day and time the calendar goes away and what is left in the text input is a text representation of the date. That's what I see if I go to edit the record as well.

I'd like to modify how that date is displayed in the text input field. In other templates where that date is displayed I can use strftime, but I don't know how (or even if it's possible) to format the value of a text input field.

Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1:** If you have a default time format for your application, `text_field` will use that.  For example, you might have a `config/initializers/time_formats.rb` containing the following:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'
```

---

**Option 2:** You can override the `text_field`'s `value` using `strftime` directly.  For example:

```
<%- scheduled_at_string = form.object.scheduled_at && form.object.scheduled_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") -%>
<%= form.text_field :scheduled_at, :value => scheduled_at_string %>
```

(You might want to clean this up with a helper.)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, but had to use a conventional HTML input element, not the Rails helper:

```
<input type="text" id="assignment_starts_at" name="assignment[starts_at]" class="jqueryCDS" size="30" value="<%= @assignment.starts_at.strftime('%A, %b %e, %G - %I:%M %p') if @assignment.starts_at %>" />
```